# Indian senior citizens visiting Canada with a 15-hour layover at Haneda Airport and flying with ANA from Delhi to Vancouver

Tags: indian-citizens, india, transit-visas, layovers, hnd

- List item

My parents, who are senior Indian citizens, are flying from Delhi to Vancouver with a layover of 15 hours at Haneda Airport, Tokyo. They are flying with the Japanese carrier ANA.

1. Will they have to get a transit visa if they stay inside the airport?
2. Can they board the connecting flight while staying in the airport (T3)?
3. Does anyone know if that airline does a through check-in for the baggages to Vancouver?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add as much detail as you are comfortable with. Most important: is this a single ticket ? What are the exact flight numbers and dates ?

Comment: @Hilmar this is how the itinerary would look. https://ibb.co/gSmXBJs

Comment: @lambshaanxy so far resources like these are suggesting that they wouldn't need a transit visa but it would be more satisfactory if a traveler could confirm this as their first hand personal experience.

Answer (score -3):

I do believe they will need a visa. Please refer to the page below for more information.
https://www.detroit.us.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/transitvisa.html

Comment: -1. That page is about *stopovers* in Japan, but the OP is asking about a transit that does not leave the airport, and Haneda is open 24/7.

Comment: Please do not add chatty lines like I hope you find this useful, make sure it is useful instead. You do that by copying the relevant information and paste that as text into the answer.